# How did Andrej Karpathy make the LSTM output byte values for sampling Shakespeare?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I'm wondering how continuous output values of deep learning networks are converted to byte values or other discrete values for that sake.

For example here: In his famous article [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/), Andrej samples Shakespeare texts using an LSTM. An LSTM's output consists of sigmoid outputs multiplied by tanh outputs:

[image]
([Understanding LSTM Networks, Christopher Olah, 2015](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/))

These values are always in the interval [-1, 1], so their product (and hence the output of the LSTM) is also in this interval. How are these values converted to byte values {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 255}?

[image]

Comment: Byte values meaning chars?  Here is the sample code that outputs the values: https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/blob/master/sample.lua#L149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach to have neural networks generate discrete outputs is to make them generate a probability distribution over the space of options. Then, you can choose the option with the highest probability, or use a different sampling strategy (i.e. beam search in text generation).

To generate a probability distribution over N options, you project the output of your model (i.e. an LSTM) to an N-dimensional space and then apply the softmax function to normalize the N components and make them add up to 1. The N-dimensional vector before the softmax is referred to as unnormalized log probabilities or "logits".

The usual loss function for this kind of discrete output is the categorical cross-entropy.

This kind of approach is used not only for text generation, but also in multi-class classification.